# SortedCollection for tuples where 'contains' considers only the first part of each tuple

Tags: python, sorting, collections, tuples

I want to write a sorted container for tuples of the form

```
('A', 'b', 1, 0.3, 0.5)
('A', 'b', 2, 0.2, 0.1)
('A', 'b', 3, 0.6, 0.4)
('B', 'e', 1, 0.1, 0.9)
('B', 'e', 2, 0.5, 0.3)
```

A tuple is considered equal if the first 3 entries are identical. The two floats at the end should be ignored for sorting.

The SortedCollection recipe from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577197-sortedcollection/ goes in the right direction, so I used it as a starting point. The ordering can be achieved by a user-defined key. What it does not do is restricting the contains method to the first n tuple elements.

For example:

```
def __contains__(self, item):
    k = self._key(item)
    i = bisect_left(self._keys, k)
    j = bisect_right(self._keys, k)
    return item in self._items[i:j]
```

The problem is that after the bisect calls, the entire item is used for the in operator. This of course compares the full content of the tuples, and that's not what I want.

The expected result is that these two tuples are considered identical

```
('A', 'b', 1, 0.3, 0.5)
('A', 'b', 1, 0.2, 0.1)
```

because the first 3 tuple elements are identical.

A fix for the in operator in contains could look like

```
return item[:2] in [ele[:2] for ele in self._items[i:j]]
```

That is of course quite costly because this list comprehension creates temporary objects each time contains is called.

Is there a more efficient way (e.g. by using islice)?

Comment: what do you want to do with the identical tuples? Remove them? I feel that you are over complicating your life here.

Comment: If a new tuple is considered identical (because the first 3 tuple elements match to an already present tuple), then I would update the old tuple in the collection. Meaning the existing tuple gets removed and replaced by the new tuple. Alternatively, the float payload of the existing tuple could be updated with the values from the new tuple. So there are never two tuples in the collection where the first 3 elements are identical.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following:

```
a = [('A', 'b', 1, 0.3, 0.5),
     ('A', 'b', 1, 0.2, 0.1),
     ('A', 'b', 1, 0.4, 0.4),
     ('A', 'b', 3, 0.6, 0.4),
     ('A', 'a', 2, 0.1, 0.3)]  # your initial list of tuples

# to get rid of the identical ones, we will use a dictionary.
b = {x[:3]:x[3:] for x in a}
print(b)  # -> {('A', 'b', 1): (0.4, 0.4), ('A', 'b', 3): (0.6, 0.4), ('A', 'a', 2): (0.1, 0.3)}
# as you see, only the latest value appears: ('A', 'b', 1, 0.4, 0.4)    

# the we built the list again from the dictionary
c = [(*k, *v) for k, v in b.items()]
print(c)  # -> [('A', 'b', 1, 0.4, 0.4), ('A', 'b', 3, 0.6, 0.4), ('A', 'a', 2, 0.1, 0.3)]

# and we finally sort based on your rules.    
d = sorted(c, key=lambda x: x[:3])
print(d)  # -> [('A', 'a', 2, 0.1, 0.3), ('A', 'b', 1, 0.4, 0.4), ('A', 'b', 3, 0.6, 0.4)]
# notice the ('A', 'a' ,..) going first.
```

Comment: My motivation why I wanted to use a sorted collection is that there will also be frequent inserts. The collection contains about 10000 tuples, and about every second there are about 1 - 10 tuples to insert. Most of the time the new tuples will be different in the first 3 tuple elements, but sometimes there is also one which already exists in the collection. Then the float payload of the existing tuple needs to be updated (or the existing tuple is completely removed + the new one inserted). Doing a sort() of a 10K long list every second is something I want to avoid.

Comment: I see. 1) Why don't you use a dictionary? 2) Why do you want them sorted? 3) Why do you want to sort every time an insertion happens?

Comment: (2) The tuple element 3 (the integer) is a time stamp. About once per minute, I need to extract a consecutive potion (about 5000) of the tuples for further processing. If the tuples are sorted, then the effort for insert and extraction is much smaller. (3) Initial sorting is fine, but a sorted insert is probably more efficient than a complete sorting. (1) A dictionary  would be fast on insert, but extracting the 5000 consecutive elements is probably slow. I apologize for not mentioning in my question that I'm dealing with a data stream where both insertion and retrieval have to be fast.

Comment: you were right, I was thinking too complicated. For the contains method, one solution is to change the IN argument from self._items to self._keys. That way, the float payload is no longer considered when testing for equality. The index and count methods need to be adjusted in a similar manner.